# RxSwift Shared Subscription Execution Order

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactive

How can I ensure that a subscriber to an `Observable` will receive the `onNext` event after another subscriber?

My example is the following:

```
let firstNameObservable = firstName.asObservable().shareReplay(1)
let lastNameObservable = lastName.asObservable().shareReplay(1)
let bioObservable = bio.asObservable().shareReplay(1)
let websiteObservable = website.asObservable().shareReplay(1)

firstNameObservable.subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] firstName in self.accountDetails.firstName = firstName }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
lastNameObservable.subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] lastName in self.accountDetails.lastName = lastName }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
bioObservable.subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] bio in self.accountDetails.bio = bio }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
websiteObservable.subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] website in self.accountDetails.website = website }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

Observable.combineLatest(firstNameObservable, lastNameObservable, bioObservable, websiteObservable)
    { [unowned self] _, _, _, _ in return self.accountDetails.validForSignUp }
    .bind(to: isValid)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I would like for that last `combineLatest` binding to trigger after any of the 4 `subscriptions` above it have already executed. This is because it is only after the properties on `accountDetails` have been set that the `validForSignUp` will be accurate.

I am aware that a solution to this problem would be to make `validForSignUp` a `Variable` and observe it, but let's assume that is not possible.

Comment: Is `isValid` a `Variable`? You should be avoiding Variables and Subjects if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something more like this:

```
let accountDetails = AccountDetails(firstName: firstName.orEmpty.asObserable(), lastName: lastName.orEmpty.asObservable(), bio: bio.orEmpty.asObservable(), website: website.orEmpty.asObservable())

accountDetails.validForSignup
    .bind(to: isValid)
    .disposed(by: bag)

struct AccountDetails {

    let validForSignup: Observable<Bool>

    init(firstName: Observable<String>, lastName: Observable<String>, bio: Observable<String>, website: Observable<String>) {

        let firstNameValid = firstName.map { $0.isValidFirstName }
        let lastNameValid = lastName.map { $0.isValidLastName }
        let bioValid = bio.map { $0.isValidBio }
        let websiteValid = website.map { $0.isValidWebsite }

        validForSignup = Observable.combineLatest([firstNameValid, lastNameValid, bioValid, websiteValid]) { $0.allTrue() }
    }
}

extension String {
    var isValidFirstName: Bool {
        return !isEmpty // put approprate code here
    }

    var isValidLastName: Bool {
        return !isEmpty // put approprate code here
    }

    var isValidBio: Bool {
        return !isEmpty // put approprate code here
    }

    var isValidWebsite: Bool {
        return !isEmpty // put approprate code here
    }

}

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Bool {

    func allTrue() -> Bool {
        return !contains(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the solution to this problem is, indeed, a different approach. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, if you are writing your reactive code such that order matters in this way, then you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle your data validation with a single subscribe. Here's how it can be done where I'll bind the combined events to an Observable that performs validation of the combined results.

```
let fields = [firstNameObservable, 
              lastNameObservable, 
              bioObservable, 
              websiteObservable]
let validFields = Observable.combineLatest(fields).bind(to: validateFields)
```

The Observable that will deliver the validation of the combined results could look something like the following function.

```
func validateFields<T>(allFields: Observable<[T]>) -> Observable<Bool>
{
    return allFields.map { fieldData in
        var result: Bool = false

        /* Is the data valid? */

        return result;
    }
}
```

The Observable `validFields` will be updated with a validation result every time there is new data from any of the field Observables. With `combineLatest`, you have the added benefit that the order of your source Observables is maintained. This solution is accomplished without resorting to storage of state making it completely reactive.

Comment: My aim was actually to ensure the execution of the validation following the setting of the `AccountDetails` properties. Whilst your answer is interesting, it doesn't necessarily give me a solution my specific problem.