# Start subscription after another subscription fires

Tags: rx-swift

There are two observables: `a` and `b`. I want to subscribe to the second observable (`b`) after first observable (`a`) has fired (i.e. has generated very first `onNext` event).

I tried

```
    b.skipUntil(a).subscribe(onNext:{
        print("B: \($0)")
    }).disposed(by: _bag)
```

but with no luck because `b` is a cold observable. As I understand, it starts immediately and gets blocked by `skipUntil(a)`.

This approach seems to work:

```
    a.subscribe(onNext:{_ in
        // ... handle a ...

        b.subscribe(onNext:{
            print("B: \($0)")
        }).disposed(by: self._bag)
    }).disposed(by: _bag)
```

but I realise this is a bad practise and not a way to go.

Comment: maybe this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44204583/rxswift-shared-subscription-execution-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple `flatMap`:

```
let c = a.flatMap { _  in b }
```

You might want to add a `.take(1)` before the flatMap or look over the different varieties of flatMap and see which one is right for your use case. And it would be best to generate the `b` observable inside the flatMap closure instead of passing it in like the above.

https://medium.com/@danielt1263/rxswifts-many-faces-of-flatmap-5764e6c2018c